# cordova-plugin-console not working anymore (ionic and phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, console, ionic-framework

The console plugin used to work great. I'm not sure exactly when it stopped but I have noticed it doesn't work anymore.

I have updated phonegap, ionic, and the plugin itself.

- phonegap version is 5.3.9
- Ionic lib is 1.2.1
- Cordova version is 5.1.1
- cordova-plugin-console is 1.0.2

When I run a phonegap serve I have no console.log events showing up in my console window as they used to do before. Has anyone run into this and is able to give me some assistance?

Comment: I have found that it works when I create new projects. So it seems to be something to do with my current projects. Time to start scratching through files...

Comment: So I found the problem. Its the content security policy header that is used with the whitelist plugin.

I have decided to just allow all for my debugging purposes and try get a word on the phonegap or plugin forums to see if there is a better way that thig: script-src *

Answer (score 0):

I got some good feedback on the phonegap community.

It seems like the answer is to either set up your own phonegap server or just use the allow all while debugging.

Here is the thread for reference. http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/whitelist-plugin-blocks-console-plugin-is-there-a-better-way-to-work-around-this-other-than-adding-script-src-to?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=16476379#reply_16476379